# library jar uses different version of Spring

Tags: spring, dependencies

My main project is using Spring v4. One of the library files (jar) uses Spring v3.

How to prevent the Spring in the library files conflicts with master project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on a build system you are using. For Maven you can **[exclude conflicting dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)**.

Comment: what if there are some api changes in Spring v4 and Spring v3? If the library depends on some methods that is found in Spring v3, but not in Spring v4, excluding v3 will break it, I guess.

Comment: In this case you're out of luck. You either have to recompile your library under Spring 4 (if you can) or switch your whole project back to Spring 3